# play-framework (java) : make a page modal

Tags: java, javascript, view, playframework, modal-dialog

> I have this view `viewAreaDesc.scala.html`:

```
@(description:String, k:String, idenv:String)
@Main("view description"){

  <div id ="areadesc" class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-7">
        <form action="@routes.Application.PostAreaDescription(k,idenv)" method="POST">

             Area Description:<br>
            <input class="form-control" value="@description" name="description" readonly>


        </form>
  </div>


}
```

> and I try to make it, a modal, when I load the page... I really can't figure this out. Because I need my parameters : `@(description:String, k:String, idenv:String)` , to be passed too ...
>   Can somebody help me ?
>   Thank you.

---

> so to be more clear ...

When i click a link, from another page ... I want this one (`viewAreaDesc.scala.html`) to be loaded like a modal !

---

> Solution: I loaded this page into the modal with jquery.

```
  $(function(){   
    // alert("aaa");
        $(".modal-body").load("page.scala.html");
    });
```

Comment: Are you going to use JavaScript to make a modal dialog when the page loads? Do you mean you're using `alert` or are you using some JS framework?

Comment: The fundamental thing for creating modals (in any framework) is to create __static__ HTML page with markup that will do what you want. When you'll know it, then you can ask how to achieve this within given tool. At the moment I have no idea, what do you want.

Comment: @Rich Dougherty : I can't use alert. The idea is that I can't target a div, because I have parameters  `@(description:String, k:String, idenv:String) ` . And I need that information. When I click a link from  `another page ` I want this one, to be loaded like a modal. I wanted to know if I can target the page : `viewAreaDesc.scala.html` ... sorry if I wasn't clear, I am new in the programming family . Something like : `window.onload = function () { beAmodal(); } ` ....

Comment: @biesior , I want to be able to make `a page` (not only a `div` or something where I can add a `class` or an `id`), modal onload. And it can be done, even if I have parameters ... only I can't do it ... yet !

Comment: @besior's advice is good. First try to create what you want using static HTML and JS. Once you've got it working, try to convert it to a template. It'll be easier for us to answer your template question once we can see what the HTML and JS you want to write is. If you don't know what JS and HTML to write then you might want to ask a separate question, e.g. "How do I show a modal dialog when a page is loaded?" tagged as "javascript".